# ArgumentOutOfRangeException в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Краду код с Хабра (вот ссылка на всю статью https://habr.com/ru/post/495588/, если нужно). Пытаюсь заставить код создавать генерируемую карту, в итоге вылезает ошибка:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index.
```

Если вкратце, то ошибка вылезает из-за:

```
public List<Feature> allFeatures;
public void GenerateDungeon()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            Feature originFeature;

            if (allFeatures.Count == 1)
            {
                originFeature = allFeatures[0];
            }
            else
            {
                originFeature = allFeatures[Random.Range(1, allFeatures.Count - 1)]; //данной строки
            }
            if (countFeatures >= maxFeatures) break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Код, рабочий, возможно у тебя меняется размер коллекции где то ещё, от этого и проблема. `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` говорит о выходе за границы массива, попробуй провести отладку, посмотреть чему равен размер массива в моменте обращения

Comment: Я проверил, как и ожидалось Юнити заставляет меня самому вводить данные allFeatures. Как заставить Юнити самому это делать?

Comment: Что значит самому Unity? Данные allFeatures наверное было задуманы так что они заполняются вручную через Инспектор, вложите скриншот как выглядит ваш инспектор

Comment: Прошу прощения, а как вложить скрин? Да и в статье Хабра в инспекторе ничего в allFeatures не надо вводить, когда у меня должно выглядеть, как то так - https://disk.yandex.ru/i/ou5DILBeRTFupQ

Comment: А где он вас заставляет вводить данные ?

Comment: Приведенный мной пример - капля того, что нужно вписать в allFeatures. Если я не пропишу все в allFeatures, то он не запуститься и все комнаты будут однотипными, а это мне не нужно, мне нужно, чтобы Юнити сам создавал карту с не однотипными квартирами.